# ¿Cómo rescato datos desde una tab?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

Dentro de una tab (QtWidgets.QTabWidget) tengo una tabla (QtWidgets.QTableWidget). Lo que yo necesito es rescatar las filas de la tabla desde una clase externa tanto a la gui que contiene a las tabs como al módulo que administra el widget de la tabla.

Para poblar la tabla no hay problemas:

```
def actualiza_noticias(self, id_hecho):
    if DEBUG: print('entra_datos:::actualiza_noticias')

    for noticia in self.lst_obj_noticias:
        if noticia.id_hecho == id_hecho:
            self.ui.tab_noticia = WTabNoticias(id_noticia=noticia.id_noticia,
                                               txt_titulo_noticia=noticia.titulo,
                                               txt_web=noticia.referencia_web,
                                               txt_bajada=noticia.noticia,
                                               date_fecha_noticia=noticia.fecha,
                                               lst_actores=self.lst_obj_personas)
            self.ui.tab_noticia.initTabNoticias(self.ui.wtab_Noticias, noticia.nombre_medio)

            # Actualiza la participación de los actores en la noticia
            self.actualiza_participacion(noticia.id_noticia)
```

Para recuperarla solo puedo llegar hasta acá:

```
def alta_participacion(self):
    if DEBUG: print('entra_datos:::alta_participacion')

    tabs = self.ui.wtab_Noticias
    for t in range(tabs.count() - 1):
        print(f'\nt{t}:', tabs.tabText(t))
```

Cualquier cosa que quiera hacer para meterme dentro de la tabla no es apropiado.

Comment: Muestra tu código. ¿cómo añades los datos a la QTableWidget? ¿Usas algún modelo de datos?

Comment: Gracias por responder, Saelyth. Agregar datos no fue problema, el problema es recuperarlos. Ahí reformulo la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Prueba `tutablewidget.model().index(1, 1).data()`, cambia el 1, 1 por los datos que necesitas (equivalen a fila y columna)

Probablemente sea más facil añadir algo así a una subclase de tu QTableWidget. Esto es tan solo un ejemplo:

```
def get_all_rows_data(self, delimiter=", "):
    """Get the data in all rows as strings, columns divided by a delimiter"""
    table_data = []
    model = self.model()
    for row in range(model.rowCount()):
        row_data = []
        for column in range(model.columnCount()):
            row_data.append(str(model.index(row, column).data()))
        table_data.append(f"{delimiter}".join(row_data))
    return table_data
```